# Parse enum from String not working

Tags: c#, enums

I have a `public enum` declared like this:

```
public enum States
    {
        SomeState,
        SomeOtherState
    }
```

Having an arbitrary string `myString` which may represent any of the "States" above, I'd like to write a switch to check which one it currently is.

This is my attempt.

```
States state = Enum.Parse(States, myString, true);
            switch (state)
            {
                case States.SomeState:
                case States.SomeOtherState:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

Inside of the `Enum.Parse()` it tells me that the argument State is being used as a type instead that as a variable. Isn't that the correct usage? The first argument Enum.Parse is supposed to receive is `Type enumType`: why then it tells me it needs a variable?

---

Many kind replies indicates to use `typeof`. Unfortunately, I've already tried that but since I receive the following error I guessed it was a wrong idea.

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(States), myString, true);
```

yields:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'States'. An explicit conversion
>   exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to send in the Type of enum that your are parsing into (using `typeof`):

```
States state = (States)Enum.Parse(typeof(States), myString, true);
```

The `Parse` method is expecting an argument of type `System.Type`.  Not *the* type `States`.

Here is the signature from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9.aspx).

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public static Object Parse(
    Type enumType,
    string value,
    bool ignoreCase
)
```

`Parse` returns an `object` so it requires you to cast to your type after the parse.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's what I tought too... Unfortunately, it is not working: please see the updated question.

Comment: You also have to cast the result.  Updating.

Comment: but of course! What an idiot I am... Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since it is expecting a type, change `Enum.Parse(States, myString, true)`; to `Enum.Parse(typeof(States), myString, true);`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct one.

```
States state = Enum.Parse(typeof(States), myString, true);
switch (state)
{
    case States.SomeState:
    case States.SomeOtherState:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
States tmp;
 Enum.TryParse<States>(myString,true ,out tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Can make it more elegant by using `extension class` like so:

```
namespace YourClass.Models;

public static E ToEnum<E>(this object value, bool ignoreCase = true) where E : Enum
{
    if(value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Value cannot be null");
    }
    return (E)Enum.Parse(typeof(E), value.ToString(), ignoreCase);
}
```

###### And using it like so:

```
States state = myString.ToEnum<States>();
```